# What's the term for consumers not being able to pay their mortgage?

Tags: finance, definition

Is there a term for not being able to pay your mortgage(s)? Like "personal bankruptcy", "consumer default" or something like that?

Comment: In which English (British, American, Indian, other?) For one payment, or a sequence of payments, or permanently? Are you asking about specific technical jargon in a particular context?

Comment: Is the distinction you are making between "can't pay" / 'won't pay" or "not paying" / "paying"?

Comment: In any English. For a any amount of payments (one, many, permanently). Yes, a technical jargon, but in general, not for a particular context. The context is in general, although the most common case is not being able to pay the mortgage for the loan you made for buying the house. I am asking strictly about "can't pay", not "won't pay" / "don't want to pay" or anything else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Not paying* a mortgage is first known as *delinquency* (when payments are missed) and later, *default* (when the loan is written down and the lender seeks foreclosure). But an inability to pay has no particular term of art attached to it, because an inability to pay can arise either out of *illiquidity* (debts exceed liquid assets) or *insolvency* (debts exceed liquid assets and ability to borrow against future income).

Answer (score 2):

Insolvent household, maybe?
For a person or a household, the most common term is insolvency.